# Drag & Drop UICollectionView cell reuse problem

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

So I've implemented drag & drop for my UICollectionView like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        guard shouldAllowDragForIndexPath?(indexPath) == true else { return [] }
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.toImage() else {
            return []
        }
        let provider = NSItemProvider(object: cell)
        let item = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
        item.localObject = data[indexPath.row]

        return [item]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        guard
            let item = coordinator.items.first?.dragItem,
            let sourceIndexPath = coordinator.items.first?.sourceIndexPath,
            let destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath,
            let entity = item.localObject as? T
            else {
                return
        }
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ [unowned self] in
            dropEntityAtIndexPath?(entity, destinationIndexPath)
            self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sourceIndexPath])
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [destinationIndexPath])
        }, completion: nil)
        coordinator.drop(item, toItemAt: destinationIndexPath)
        item.localObject = nil
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        if
            session.localDragSession != nil,
            let path = destinationIndexPath,
            shouldAllowDropForIndexPath?(path) == true {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
        }
    }
```

Everything working but I've spotted strange behavior when the cell is being reused.
Here is video: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uojS.jpg)

So it only happens after cells were being dragged, also it seems like there is some gray overlay view, but I cannot see it on view debugger. Also, I've tried to set my cell's `imageView.image = nil` in `prepareForReuse` but it didn't help. I would be very grateful if someone helps me fix this. Thanks.

**Edit1:** Code in `cellForItemAt`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: PhotoCollectionViewCell.self)
        let container = data[indexPath.row].postContainer,
        let post = container.postMedia.first
        let isCarousel = container.isCarousel
        let isVideo = post.isVideo
        let _isSelected = isSelected?(indexPath) ?? false
        let url = post.thumbURL?.toURL()
        let isScheduled = container.schedulerFor != nil
        let fromInstagram = false

        cell.configure(url: url, isSelected: _isSelected, isVideo: isVideo, isCarousel: isCarousel, isScheduled: isScheduled, fromInstagram: fromInstagram)

    return cell
}
```

**Edit 2**
Cell configuration function:

```
func configure(url: URL?, isSelected: Bool = false, isVideo: Bool = false, isCarousel: Bool = false, isScheduled: Bool = false, fromInstagram: Bool = false) {
        checkmarkImageView.isHidden = !isSelected
        selectionOverlay.isHidden = !isSelected
        isVideoImageView.isHidden = !isVideo
        carouselImageView.isHidden = !isCarousel
        cornerImageView.image = isScheduled ? R.image.cyanCorner() : R.image.grayCorner()
        instagramImageView.isHidden = !fromInstagram
        cornerImageView.isHidden = fromInstagram
        url.map(imageView.setImage(with:))
    }
```

Comment: What does your `cellForItem(at:)` function look like?

Comment: @JacobRelkin Added to the question.

Comment: ...and what does your `configure` function look like?

Comment: @JacobRelkin Added to the question.

Comment: Does it happen only within a certain timeframe after completing the drop operation or always after scrolling?

Comment: @JacobRelkin Always after scrolling if drag & drop happened before.

Comment: Is it necessary to use itemsForBeginning, performDropWith and dropSessionDidUpdate instead of using just ---- override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {   } ?

Comment: @BohdanSavych did you manage to find a solution? I'm facing the same problem, and there is nothing that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not a cell reuse, but improper model update. `item.localData` should be updated properly when movement is finished.

It means that you must update your data model object before you call `UICollectionView` update.

Here is the example for `UICollectionViewDelegate`, but only these line actually matters:

```
// YOUR MODEL OBJECT is expected to be a list-like data structure
YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT.insert(YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT.remove(at: sourceIndex), at: destinationIndex)
```

How it works for `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard destinationIndexPath != sourceIndexPath else { return }
    // YOUR MODEL OBJECT is expected to be a list-like data structure
    YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT.insert(YOUR_MODEL_OBJECT.remove(at: sourceIndex), at: destinationIndex)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your solution and it didn't help me :(